# Filling whole area under the curve in ggvis

Tags: r, plot, shiny, data-visualization, ggvis

I'm trying to create a simple chart in ggvis using `layer_lines()` and want to have the area underneath it have a fill color. For some reason, when I try the most basic things that should be able to do it, I get unusual results.

For example, I tried setting `fill` for `layer_lines()`, and it ended up looking like this:
[image]

Then I tried using `layer_ribbons()` with `fill` and it looks like this:

[image]

I basically want the exact opposite of what I got in the picture above.

Here's my complete plot code:

```
valuePlot <-  valueTable %>%
  ggvis(~date, ~revenue) %>%
  layer_points(fill := "black", opacity := 0, size := 300) %>%
  layer_lines(fill := "darkgreen", stroke := "darkgreen", strokeWidth := 2) %>%
  set_options(width = "auto", height = 300, resizable=FALSE) %>%
  add_axis("x", title= xaxis) %>%
  add_axis("x", orient = "top", ticks = 0, title = main, title_offset = -5,
           properties = axis_props(
             axis = list(stroke = "white"),
             labels = list(fontSize = 0))) %>%
  add_axis("y", title= yaxis, title_offset = 60) %>%
  add_tooltip(ttip, "hover")
```

I included the above in case one of the random things I have in there is causing the problem. A more reproducible, simpler example would be:

```
  mtcars %>%
  ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>%
  layer_lines(fill := "darkgreen", stroke := "darkgreen", strokeWidth := 2) %>%
  set_options(width = "auto", height = 300, resizable=FALSE) %>%
  add_axis("x", title="x axis") %>%
  add_axis("y", title="y axis", title_offset = 60) %>%
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Usually funny lines are caused by the values not being sorted properly, since it is common for lines to be drawn between consecutive points in the raw data.  Here, you can order the data by "wt" then fill, setting the `y` and `y2` bounds appropriately,

```
mtcars %>%
  dplyr::arrange(wt) %>%
  ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>%
  layer_ribbons(y = ~mpg, fill := "lightgreen") %>%     # fill above
  layer_ribbons(y2 = ~min(mpg)-1, fill := "darkgreen"   # fill below
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In the case of my actual code, I'm plotting against dates which are in order, so I can't really rearrange the set anymore. How would I apply this example to that? Also, why the `y2 = ~min(mpg)-1` part?

Answer (score 0):

Layer_ribbons wants a set of values, a min and a max, so to speak. You've already given it what you want as your max by mapping `~revenue` to the y axis in the original ggvis call.

But you need to add a y2 coordinate. In your case, you want y2 to always equal 0 because you want the ribbon to stretch down to 0 for every point of data.

So something like this:

```
valueTable %>%
arrange(date) %>% # looks like you've probably already done this
ggvis(~date, ~revenue) %>%
layer_ribbons( y2 = 0, fill := 'darkgreen')
```